# SwiftUI: Combining Custom Text

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

With the `SwiftUI` built-in `Text` we are able to concatenate multiple `Text` views if we want to create a rich Text

like this:

```
Text("hello").foregroundColor(.white) + Text("world").foregroundColor(.pink)
```

However, if I have a custom Text:

```
struct MyText: View {

  let label: String

  var body: some View {
      Text(self.label)
         .foregroundColor(.myAppColor)
  }
}
```

and then combine:

```
MyText(label: "hello") + MyText(label: "world")
```

the compiler outputs the following error:

```
Referencing operator function '+' on 'FloatingPoint' requires that 'MyText' conform to 'FloatingPoint'
```

I tried casting `MyText` to Text but the compiler doesn't like that either.

How do I go about achieving this in a slick manner?

Comment: What's the purpose of replication? Why do you need to wrap Text? And what's about those "custom modifiers", if they are not resulting in Text then concatenating will not be possible anyway.

Comment: The problem is that your MyText is _not_ a "custom text". It's just a View.

Comment: @Asperi I have edited the question as it was misleading. I am using plane modifiers like `foregroundColor` etc... and as for the reason for the wrapping: I am using the exact same style extensively in my app and seems more appropriate to have my custom text

Comment: @matt I am welll aware of this. I understand why the compiler is resisting me. my question is how do I enable combination despite this. makes sense?

Comment: It doesn't make sense (to me) _why_ you want to do it that way, no.

Answer (score 0):

This is a custom feature of `Text`, you can, however, mimick some of the behaviour. See the following example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyText: View {
    
    private let configurations: [Configuration]
    
    init(_ title: String, foregroundColor: Color = .black) {
        self.configurations = [
            .init(title: title,
                  foregroundColor: foregroundColor)
        ]
    }
    
    private init(configurations: [Configuration]) {
        self.configurations = configurations
    }
    
    private struct Configuration: Identifiable {
        let id = UUID()
        let title: String
        let foregroundColor: Color
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(configurations, content: Render.init)
        }
    }

    static func + (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self {
        let configurations = lhs.configurations + rhs.configurations
        return MyText(configurations: configurations)
    }
    
    private struct Render: View {
        let configuration: Configuration
        var body: some View {
            Text(configuration.title)
                .foregroundColor(configuration.foregroundColor)
        }
    }
}

struct MyText_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MyText("hej") + MyText("Yo", foregroundColor: .red)
    }
}
```

This is much more a proof of concept, than an advice to do this practice however.